# Attach and detach In ManyToMany Relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I have an `EmployeeSkill` model and the table is `employee_skills`, columns are `id`, `employee_id`, `skill_id`

When creating a user, I can assign multiple skills and I want to assign all skills id for the specific user id in the `employee_skills` table.

I have the `Employees` and `Skill` models.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you have tried, this can also clarify what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

In `many to many` relationships between two entities, We have two models and a third table. for more explanation see [this](https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/help/18/fmp/en/index.html#page/FMP_Help/many-to-many-relationships.html) and [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

you don't need the `EmployeeSkill` model, delete this, and accord to the laravel recommendation the third table name is better to be singular and in alphabetical order, like this: `employee_skill`.

Employee model relation:

```php
public function skills()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Skill::class);
}
```

Skil model relation:

```php
public function employees()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Employee::class);
}
```

now when you wanna assign all skills id for a specific employee, you just need to `attach` or `sync`:

```php
$employee->skills()->sync({...you skills id...})

// -----

$employee->skills()->attach({...you skills id...})
```

Comment: What for update because i may remove previous skills and add new one then how to remove previous skills from employee_skills and add new one.

Comment: if you use the sync method, this will be solved because sync first detach all skills and then attach the skills that you send as a parameter.